# How to troubleshoot PL/SQL block that contains WITH clauses?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

My workflow follows: I developed some SQL statements according to a certain logic. Then I am asked to bundle the SQL statement into PL/SQL block to help trigger/schedule the execution of said statements.
At that point, I can see that PL/SQL block (despite being copy/paste of the SQL statement + passing argument) does not give the same results.

While I can `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` the arguments to check they are what was intended, I did not find a way to peek into what happens in the `WITH` clause of the `SELECT` statement.
I tried `SELECT INTO` a local variable of the PL/SQL block, but it is not allowed to do `SELECT INTO` if not at the outer-most SELECT (which is never going to be the case in an element of a `WITH` clause).

So the question is how to troubleshoot this type of statement?

I don't have an MRE, I am looking for a general solution to change my workflow rather than a workaround for this case.

Note: I am fine with a high-level answer so long I could practically use it. (for instance: "never use `WITH` clause in PL/SQL" would be fine).
Note: I say "troubleshoot", because I can't debug as the DBA didn't grant debug rights, and ETA to get debug rights granted is more than 12 months away.

Comment: Please post your sample code and the error you are getting.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a minimal example of **YOUR** code that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve because it is not clear from your text what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You could possibly use a ref cursor to see what the query, or just the CTE, returns. Or turn the query into a cursor and loop over and print the results. But the question is too vague to be able to give any kind of proper answer.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I don't have a a sample code to share because I don't know in which direction to go. I could give you an example of a failing "select into" giving but I already know why it is falling and why I can't use it. what I do not know is what else I should do.

Comment: @MT0, I am sorry I am not able to provide a MRE, for the reasons mentioned in the question. In short I am not looking for a solution in this particular case, I am trying to find a general workflow in which I could troubleshoot WITH clauses that are executed in a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what is going on with a `WITH` clause such as:

```
WITH sqfc1 (a, b, c, d, e) AS (
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  f = 'something'
),
sqfc2 (a, b, c, d, m) AS (
  SELECT a, b, c, d, 2 * e + d
  FROM   sqfc1
  WHERE  a > 0 OR b > 0
)
SELECT a, d, m, b + c AS n
FROM   sqfc2
WHERE  m > 3 AND d > 0;
```

and you want to see what is going on in the first sub-query factoring clause then just repeat the SQL statement and stop after the first clause:

```
WITH sqfc1 (a, b, c, d, e) AS (
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  f = 'something'
)
SELECT *
FROM   sqfc1
```

And you will see what is going on.

---

> Then I am asked to bundle the SQL statement into PL/SQL block ... how to troubleshoot this type of statement?

Do exactly the same thing but wrap it in a cursor or use `BULK COLLECT INTO` and then loop through the cursor or collection and print the rows with `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    WITH sqfc1 (a, b, c, d, e) AS (
      SELECT a, b, c, d, e
      FROM   table_name
      WHERE  f = 'something'
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM   sqfc1
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.a || ', ' || r.b || ', ' || r.c || ', ' || r.d || ', ' || r.e);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8f57d0da9369a31b7180b56fd4674cc)*